# Mouse Up in selenium webdiver 2 ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have to click on a jquery dropdown with selenium. Found that

```
MouseUp[xpath=//a[contains(text(),'itemname')]
```

works in IDE. But am at loss, as I cannot simulate this in ruby webdriver. Is it possible to simulate it with actions class? If so how? Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Filling out forms part on the Selenium WebDriver Docs http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms

This should lead you in the right direction for your problem.

Comment: Hi, I found that alternative is to use runscript for the jquery. But am not able to run it as I am getting $("#country_id") is null. Kindly help me out.